# Can an Integrated Circuit ROM ever be secured

Tags: integrated-circuit, security

This [presentation which includes embedding public asymmetric crypto assets in a micro-controller on chip ROM](https://github.com/RidiculousRichard/presentations/blob/master/12%20steps%20to%20firmware%20packages.odp?raw=true) suggests that there are, but I am sceptical.
Is it the case that there is nothing that can ever be done to hide the physical chip design from an examiner

Comment: ROM physical design part of the question split out into https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/456331/do-any-on-chip-roms-manage-to-significantly-increase-the-extraction-difficulty-o

Comment: Smart card chips integrate some countermeasures to make it very difficult to extract both ROM and EEPROM data. Search for papers in that field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must identify your expected adversary and describe their capabilities. If your adversary is the intelligence services of some reasonable country then none of these steps will protect your ROM. Imagine someone has access to a complete physical analysis lab, including a scanning electron microscope. Security through obscurity is no security at all.

Using a different personalization for the ROM in different fab runs is not a **manufacturing** problem, it's just a matter of using a different mask for the contact layer. However, it is expensive and someone needs to be careful to use the correct mask for each run.

Comment: Are you saying that all claims count as security though obscurity and so should not be classified as a meaningful security measure against any adversary?  I certainly understand your point about the capabilities of an adversary.

Comment: Yes, I'm saying that if you rely on security through obscurity like this then you must be assuming that your adversary is the average garage hacker, or that your product has a low value and it's not worth an expensive reverse engineering process. Some of the suggestions made in that presentation, such as scattering the ROM among the digits [sic] are not practical. The presentation also did not consider any side-channel attacks, such as variations in supply current as instructions are executed.